# advanced select in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

i got this Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Table (
    old_val VARCHAR2(3),
    new_val VARCHAR2(3),
    Updflag NUMBER,
    WorkNo NUMBER  );
```

and this is in my Table:

```
INSERT INTO Test_Table  (old_val, new_val, Updflag , WorkNo) VALUES('1',' 20',0,0);
INSERT INTO Test_Table  (old_val, new_val, Updflag , WorkNo) VALUES('2',' 20',0,0);
INSERT INTO Test_Table  (old_val, new_val, Updflag , WorkNo) VALUES('2',' 30',0,0);
INSERT INTO Test_Table  (old_val, new_val, Updflag , WorkNo) VALUES('3',' 30',0,0);    
INSERT INTO Test_Table  (old_val, new_val, Updflag , WorkNo) VALUES('4',' 40',0,0);
INSERT INTO Test_Table  (old_val, new_val, Updflag , WorkNo) VALUES('4',' 40',0,0);
```

now my Table Looks like this:

```
Row  Old_val  New_val       Updflag  WorkNo
1    '1'        ' 20'       0        0
2    '2'        ' 20'       0        0
3    '2'        ' 30'       0        0
4    '3'        ' 30'       0        0
5    '4'        ' 40'       0        0
6    '5'        ' 40'       0        0
```

(if the value in the `new_val` column are same then they are together and the same goes to `old_val`)
so in the example above row 1-4 are together and row 5-6

at the moment i have in my Stored Procedure a cursor:

```
 SELECT t1.Old_val, t1.New_val, t1.updflag, t1.WorkNo
    FROM Test_Table t1
    WHERE t1.New_val =
      (
        SELECT t2.New_val
        FROM Test_Table t2
        WHERE t2.Updflag = 0
          AND t2.Worknr = 0
          AND ROWNUM = 1
      )
```

the output is this:

```
Row  Old_val  New_val   Updflag  WorkNo
1    1         20       0        0
2    2         20       0        0
```

my Problem is, i dont know how to get row 1 to 4 with one select.
(i had an idea with 4 sub-querys but this wont work if its more data that matches together)

does anyone of you have an idea?

Comment: Can you show us what you would want returned? Is it that you want everything that "is together" returned? If so, wouldn't rows 1-4 and 5-6 be returned and thus all rows?

Comment: well the bottom of my post is waht i have now. and yes i want row 1-4 returned the first time if i use the script a 2nd time i want row 5-6 etc...(there is an update after the select.) i think the answer from `Vincent Malgrat` is perfect if i can lock the selected rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use analytics to define groups of contiguous rows:

```
SQL> SELECT old_val, new_val, updflag, workno,
  2         SUM(gap) over(ORDER BY old_val, new_val) grp
  3    FROM (SELECT t.*,
  4                  CASE
  5                     WHEN new_val = lag(new_val)
  6                                    over(ORDER BY old_val, new_val)
  7                       OR old_val = lag(old_val)
  8                                    over(ORDER BY old_val, new_val)
  9                     THEN
 10                      0
 11                     ELSE
 12                      1
 13                  END gap
 14             FROM Test_Table t);

OLD_VAL NEW_VAL    UPDFLAG     WORKNO        GRP
------- ------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1        20              0          0          1
2        20              0          0          1
2        30              0          0          1
3        30              0          0          1
4        40              0          0          2
4        40              0          0          2
```

The inner SELECT builds a "GAP" column that equals 1 when the current row is not in the same group as the preceeding.

The outer SELECT uses a running total over the gap column to get the group number.

#### Edit 2

You can't add the FOR UPDATE clause directly to the query because of the analytic functions. You can query the base table directly however:

```
SQL> WITH t_new AS (
  2  SELECT t_rowid, old_val, new_val, updflag, workno,
  3         SUM(gap) over(ORDER BY old_val, new_val) grp
  4    FROM (SELECT t.*, t.rowid t_rowid,
  5                  CASE
  6                     WHEN new_val = lag(new_val)
  7                                    over(ORDER BY old_val, new_val)
  8                       OR old_val = lag(old_val)
  9                                    over(ORDER BY old_val, new_val)
 10                     THEN
 11                      0
 12                     ELSE
 13                      1
 14                  END gap
 15             FROM test_table t)
 16  )
 17  SELECT *
 18    FROM test_table
 19   WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT t_rowid
 20                     FROM t_new
 21                    WHERE grp = (SELECT grp
 22                                   FROM t_new t2
 23                                  WHERE t2.new_val = ' 20'
 24                                    AND t2.old_val = '1'))
 25     FOR UPDATE;

OLD_VAL NEW_VAL    UPDFLAG     WORKNO
------- ------- ---------- ----------
1        20              0          0
2        20              0          0
2        30              0          0
3        30              0          0
```

Comment: oh cool didnt know there were a Function to get the previous values.
well this works well, but would it be possible to alter it so, that only the Rows with GRP 1 is showed?

Comment: ah its works :D
i changed the `WHERE t2.new_val = ' 20' AND t2.old_val = '1'` with `where rownum = 1` it has the same effect.

Comment: would it be possible to use for update in this statement? coze i need to lock this rows till they r updated?!

Comment: thx!
i used ur script as a subquerry and it wokrs fine!
thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is all rows that "are together with something" returned, then it does not appear that your original sample data provides a row that shouldn't be returned. So, let's add the following:

```
INSERT INTO Test_Table  (old_val, new_val, Updflag , WorkNo) VALUES('6',' 50',0,0);
```

This row shouldn't be together with anything and shouldn't be returned. Given that, I think we can use an EXISTS to get what you want:

```
Select *
From Test_Table T1
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From Test_Table T2
                Where ( T2.old_val = T1.old_val Or T2.new_val = T1.new_val )
                    And ( T2.row <> T1.row )
                )
```

Comment: i get an error `ORA-00904` at this: And `( T2.row <> T1.row )` 
in my examples the Row is only for showing which row i mean.

Comment: @Auro - Then you would replace "row" with the primary key of Test_Table.