# how to calculate accumulated numbers for a column?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, view, plsql

If I already have the columns of MYHOUR and STATUS in a table, and only these two columns, how can I create a view to calculate the OFF_HOURS column? The OFF_HOURS column is continuous 'OFF' status number. Thanks.

```
MYHOUR STATUS   OFF_HOURS
------ -------- --------
     1 OFF      1
     2 OFF      2
     3 ON       0
     4 ON       0
     5 ON       0
     6 ON       0
     7 ON       0
     8 OFF      1
     9 OFF      2
    10 OFF      3
    11 ON       0
    12 ON       0
    13 OFF      1
    14 OFF      2
    15 OFF      3
    16 OFF      4
    17 OFF      5
    18 OFF      6
    19 OFF      7
    20 OFF      8
    21 OFF      9
    22 OFF      10
    23 OFF      11
    24 OFF      12
```

Below are the scripts to create the example table and data.

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Table (
myHour  INTEGER,
status VARCHAR2(8));

BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..2
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO Test_Table VALUES (i, 'OFF');
  END LOOP;

  FOR i IN 3..7
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO Test_Table VALUES (i, 'ON');
  END LOOP;

  FOR i IN 8..10
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO Test_Table VALUES (i, 'OFF');
  END LOOP;

  FOR i IN 11..12
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO Test_Table VALUES (i, 'ON');
  END LOOP;

  FOR i IN 13..24
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO Test_Table VALUES (i, 'OFF');
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: what do you mean, "get the off_hours column"? You want to calculate the cumulative off times automatically?

Comment: John - What would be the expected output in this case?

Comment: I have only MYHOUR and STATUS columns in the table, and I want to have a view with a OFF_HOURS column which is how many 'OFF' hours for current hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use analytics:

```
SQL> SELECT myhour,
  2         status,
  3         CASE
  4            WHEN status = 'OFF' THEN
  5             COUNT(*)
  6                over(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY myhour)
  7            ELSE
  8             0
  9         END off_hours
 10    FROM (SELECT myhour, status,
 11                 SUM(offwork) over(ORDER BY myhour) grp
 12            FROM (SELECT myhour,
 13                         status,
 14                         CASE
 15                            WHEN status
 16                                 != lag(status) over(ORDER BY myhour) THEN
 17                             1
 18                         END offwork
 19                    FROM Test_Table))
 20  ORDER BY myhour;

 MYHOUR STATUS    OFF_HOURS
------- -------- ----------
      1 OFF               1
      2 OFF               2
      3 ON                0
      4 ON                0
      5 ON                0
      6 ON                0
      7 ON                0
      8 OFF               1
      9 OFF               2
     10 OFF               3
     11 ON                0
     12 ON                0
     13 OFF               1
     14 OFF               2
     15 OFF               3
     16 OFF               4
     17 OFF               5
     18 OFF               6
     19 OFF               7
     20 OFF               8
     21 OFF               9
     22 OFF              10
     23 OFF              11
     24 OFF              12
```

---

Also more simply:

```
SELECT myhour,
       status,
       CASE
          WHEN status = 'OFF' THEN
           myhour - nvl(last_value(CASE WHEN status = 'ON' 
                                        THEN myhour
                                   END IGNORE NULLS) 
                                   over(ORDER BY myhour), 0) 
       END
  FROM Test_Table;
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i81407), while a bit bland, is complete. You can find examples here on SO (such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721744/advanced-select-in-stored-procedure)) or on the [AskTom](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:asktom.oracle.com%20analytics) site.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the MyHour values are sequential, you can do this most easily with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select MAX(MyHour) from t t2 where t2.MyHour <= t.MyHour and t2.status = 'ON'
       ) - MyHour
from t
```

There is a solution using analytic functions, but it is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I think select count(*) from... where status = 'off' group by my hour is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a recursive query:

```
With CTE (myHour, status, Off_Hours) AS (
  SELECT myHour, status, CASE WHEN status = 'Off' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Off_Hours
  FROM Test_Table
  WHERE myHour = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT T.myHour, T.status,  CASE WHEN T.status = 'Off' THEN CTE.Off_Hours + 1 ELSE 0 END as Off_Hours
  FROM CTE 
     INNER JOIN Test_Table T on CTE.myHour + 1 = T.myHour
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

And here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa0b7/1).